# How do I get the Troupple Acolyte achievement?

Tags: achievements, shovel-knight

The in game feats list state "Discover the secrets of the Troupple King."
I have talked to the Troupple Acolyte in the cellar in the city. I have also visited the Troupple King and bathed and fished in his pond but I have not gotten the achievement.

How do I get the achievement Troupple Acolyte?

Comment: (It is one of the most acquired achievements so I feel like Im missing something basic.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You go to the Troupple King's pond and let him fill your chalice and watch his dance and you will have the achievement.

Talk to him by pressing up.